# Problem with Sign PDF by SHA1 when use iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, sha1

I have a digital signature problem with PDF files, the process is as follows:
- I have a PDF file on the Server, then I locate the signature and convert it to byte format [] with SHA1.
- The client will retrieve the signature from the USB token to assign to byte [] transmitted from the server.
- I then returned the server to assign the signature.

But when I code as below, the program still runs normally without error, but the USB signature contents are not signed into the pdf file. Please help me to fix it.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UnsingnedPdf = @"E:\PrintContractAdviceNote.pdf";
        string TempPdf = @"E:\PrintContractAdviceNote_TMP.pdf";
        string singnedPdf = @"E:\PrintContractAdviceNote_Sign.pdf";
        PDFSigning cl = new PDFSigning();
        cl.GetBytesToSign(UnsingnedPdf, TempPdf, singnedPdf, "CHUKY1", 3, "BIG BEAR");

    }




    public static X509Certificate2 selectCert()
    {

        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            if (store.Certificates.Count == 1)
            {
                //Return the certificate present.
                certificate = store.Certificates[0];
            }
            else if (store.Certificates.Count > 0)
            {
                // Request the user to select a certificate 
                try
                {
                    var certificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates,
                        "Digital Certificates", "Select a certificate from the following list:",
                        X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);


                    // Check if one has been returned
                    if (certificates.Count == 1)
                    {
                        certificate = certificates[0];

                        var newCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.RawData, "mypassword");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Please select a certificate to publish PnL to Flash");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There is no certificate available to publish PnL to flash, please contact support.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
        return certificate;
    }


    public class IpInfo
    {
        //country
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, Int16 iType, string SignName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(tempPdf))
            File.Delete(tempPdf);
        if (File.Exists(signedPdf))
            File.Delete(signedPdf);
        byte[] array = null;
        bool Islock = true;
        FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        using (PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0'))
        {

            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Contact = "www.marico.com";
            appearance.SignDate = dt;
            //BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(HttpContent.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Font/arial.ttf"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            //Font font = new Font(bf, 8);
            //appearance.Layer2Font = font;
            appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS;
            appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
            appearance.Acro6Layers = true;
            appearance.Layer2Text = "Signed by:" + Environment.NewLine + "   " + SignName + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + Environment.NewLine + "   " + dt.ToShortDateString() + " " + dt.ToShortTimeString();
            Image img;
            if (iType == 3)
            {

                img = Image.GetInstance(@"E:\Tài liệu\Marico\HINH ANH\talent.png");
                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(15, 50, 235, 95), reader.NumberOfPages, signatureFieldName);
            }
            else
            {
                img = Image.GetInstance(@"E:\Tài liệu\Marico\HINH ANH\talent.png");
                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(350, 50, 570, 95), reader.NumberOfPages, signatureFieldName);
            }
            appearance.SignatureGraphic = img;
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
            array = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());
            stamper.Dispose();
            stamper.Close();
        }
        if (iType != 3)
        {
            while (Islock)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                reader.Close();
                os.Dispose();
                os.Close();
                Islock = IsFileLocked(unsignedPdf);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            reader.Close();
            os.Dispose();
            os.Close();
        }
        X509Certificate2 cert = selectCert();
        RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(cert.PrivateKey);
        formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
        byte[] signature = formatter.CreateSignature(array);






        EmbedSignature(tempPdf, signedPdf, signatureFieldName, signature);

        return (array);
    }


    public static bool IsFileLocked(string pathfile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathfile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                fs.Dispose();
                fs.Close();
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private static void SetSigPosition(PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance, int oldSigCount, string signatureFieldName, int numpage = 1)
    {
        float llx = (200 + 20) * (oldSigCount % 5) + 20,
                lly = (25 + 20) * (oldSigCount / 5) + 5,
                urx = llx + 200,
                ury = lly + 45;

    }
    public void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
    {
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);

        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
            {
                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
                reader.Dispose();
                reader.Close();
                os.Dispose();
                os.Close();
            }

        }

    }

    private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
        {
            this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            return signedBytes;
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"but the USB signature contents are not signed into the pdf file"* - what exactly do you mean by this? Is "PrintContractAdviceNote_Sign.pdf" not created at all? Or is it created but not a complete pdf? Or is it a complete pdf but no signature is embedded in the placeholder? Or is something is embedded in the placeholder but not the expected signature container.

Comment: PrintContractAdviceNote_Sign.pdf is created,the PDF file is signed but there is no certificate section. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sp_trzdvyPXaJKqC96tAFsiD3CfnItDU/view

Comment: Nobody can't help  ??

Comment: Please share the PDF files (PrintContractAdviceNote.pdf, PrintContractAdviceNote_TMP.pdf, and PrintContractAdviceNote_Sign.pdf) for analysis.

Comment: It's here  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BEky8xLH22ocIe9H69UMsksrLWBi-tWn?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, the base issue is that you only create a naked PKCS#1 style signature while you need to create a PKCS#7/CMS signature container. You can use iText's `PdfPKCS7` class or BouncyCastle classes (or something similar) for this based on your `RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter` usage, or you can use other `System.Security.*` classes to do this in a single step. I'll try and look into that later but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: Thank your help , i will try you step... hope can fix it.